# Static analysis to eliminate data dependencies

Tags: compiler-optimization, theory

I would like to learn better about static code optimization algorithms, specifically eliminating the data dependency of modern compilers.Unfortunately I can't find suitable literature, can someone help with this?
For example, I would be interested to know what transformations take place on the AST tree